# I lack access to create users as root user on mysql over php script

Tags: php, mysqli

I've created a simple script using PHP and MySQLi. The purpose is to create a new user on a MySQL server, however I get this error message: "user create query failed:Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation."

```
$db = "xsxx";
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1',"root","",$db);
$cruser= "CREATE USER '".$user."'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY  '".$pass."';";
#mysqli_query($con, $gruser) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

if(mysql_query($cruser)){
    echo 'user created<br/>';

}   else{
    echo 'user create query failed:'.mysql_error().'<br/>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? If it's important, I'm using XAMPP for the MYSQL server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the old and new style mysql calls (mysql vs mysqli).

The `mysql_query` call you are issuing will use whatever username and password was specified during the `mysql_connect` call, and importantly, not the username and password you specified in the `mysqli_connect` call.

If you are not issuing a `mysql_connect()` yourself (it's not shown in the code you posted) then the `mysql_query` will call `mysql_connect` with no arguments which leads to a blank username and password.

By whichever method it's being called, the `mysql_connect` user does not have the "CREATE USER" privilege and so the error message is generated.

You can use `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'someuser'@'localhost';` to check what a user's permissions are.

You can also use the [GRANT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) to add additional permissions to users.

An example of adding the create user permission would be: 
`GRANT CREATE_USER ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'localhost''`

One way to resolve the issue, assuming root has all permissions, is to change your `mysqli_connect` to a `mysql_connect` such as: `mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','')`